# What does AttributeError: 'LpElement' object has no attribute 'cat' and why is this error produced?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to model the following equation using Python PuLP

[image]

I have written the following Python Code

```
prob = LpProblem('Resource', LpMaximize)

# x variables

xs = [LpVariable("x{0}{1}{2}".format(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1), cat = "Binary")

    for i in range(0, 3)
    for j in range(0, 5)
    for k in range(0, 2)
]

print("\nX Variable\n")

for i in range(0, len(xs)):
    print(xs[i])

# y variables

ys = [LpVariable("y{0}{1}".format(i + 1, j + 1), cat = "Binary")

    for i in range(0, 3)
    for j in range(0, 5)
]

print("\nY Variable\n")
for i in range(0, len(ys)):
    print(ys[i])


for j in range(0, 5):
    for k in range(0, 2):
    for i in range(0, 3):
    con = "x{0}{1}{2} <= y{3}{4}".format(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1, i + 1, j + 1)
prob += LpAffineExpression(LpElement(con))
print(con)

status = prob.solve()
```

This gives the following PuLP error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python34\Cloud 3.py", line 446, in 
>       resource(request, pmachine, l, q)
>     File "C:\Python34\Cloud 3.py", line 136, in resource
>       status = prob.solve()
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1643, in solve
>       status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\solvers.py", line 1303, in actualSolve
>       return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\solvers.py", line 1325, in solve_CBC
>       tmpMps, rename = 1)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1431, in writeMPS
>       if mip and v.cat == LpInteger:
>   AttributeError: 'LpElement' object has no attribute 'cat'

What does `AttributeError: 'LpElement' object has no attribute 'cat'` and why is this error produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AttributeError: 'LpElement' object has no attribute 'cat'` is produced when there is an incompatibility between the problem variable which in this case is `prob = LpProblem('Resource', LpMaximize)` and the constraint being added.

This can be fixed by getting rid of the redundant `LpAffineExpression(LpElement(con))` calls when the variables are defined using the PuLP specified `LpVariable.dicts` instead of dynamic generation of variables as has been done above.

A better approach incorporating the changes would be as follows:

```
prob = LpProblem('Resource', LpMaximize)

xdict = LpVariable.dicts('', ["x{0}{1}{2}".format(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1)
        for i in range(0, len(request))
        for j in range(0, len(pmachine))
        for k in range(0, pmachine[j].npj)
    ],
    0, 1, cat = 'Binary')

ydict = LpVariable.dicts('', ["y{0}{1}".format(i + 1, j + 1)
        for i in range(0, len(request))
        for j in range(0, len(pmachine))
    ],
    0, 1, cat = 'Binary')

for i in range(0, len(request)):
    for j in range(0, len(pmachine)):
        for k in range(0, pmachine[j].npj):
            con = xdict["x{0}{1}{2}".format(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1)] <= ydict["y{0}{1}".format(i + 1, j + 1)]
            prob += con
            print(con)
```